# How to test what type of mode a Ruby File was opened in?

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

Say you are handed an open `File` object, but you have no clue what type of mode it was opened in (e.g 'r','w','w+').

How would you go about determining which mode the file is opened in?

As far as I can tell there isn't an `IO` method for this, but I could be missing something.

If it's necessary to write an individual test for each mode, then ideally it would be a single method or one liner `if` statement that would not modify the pointer position (or the file's contents).

Comment: The only obvious one that I know of is `IO#binmode?`; I have no clue about write/read, except by exception testing like @Arcturus advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try any of:

- Write a single character to the file descriptor, and then unseek back; if you succeed you are in write mode, otherwise you raise an exception.
- Try and glean information of the `fstat` method.

Comment: Just to be sure, by `fstat` do you mean [File::stat](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-stat)?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact Ruby function call; fstat() is the system call that does same thing as stat() but with file descriptors, as opposed to file names.

Answer (score -1):

The Ruby File object has the following methods:

```
File(filename).readable?
File(filename).writeable?
File(filename).executeable?
```

Comment: To my knowledge the `readable?` and `writable?` tests if the user has permissions, not if a specific object was opened with say `File.open('testfile.txt' 'w+')`. Correct me if I'm wrong on this.